# Warning Illegal string offset in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, offset

I have this chunk of PHP code which is giving me the error:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'mod_modulecode' in C:\xampp\htdocs\MP\multi\functions.php on line 29

This is the code that the warning is relating to:

```
function set_rights($menus, $menuRights) {
    $data = array();
    for ($i = 0, $c = count($menus); $i < $c; $i++) {
        $row = array();
        for ($j = 0, $c2 = count($menuRights); $j < $c2; $j++) {
            if ($menuRights[$j]["rr_modulecode"] == $menus[$i]["mod_modulecode"]) {
                if (authorize($menuRights[$j]["rr_create"]) || authorize($menuRights[$j]["rr_edit"]) ||
                        authorize($menuRights[$j]["rr_delete"]) || authorize($menuRights[$j]["rr_view"])
                ) {...................'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does your `$menus` array contains `mod_modulecode` key? If it contains, then your loop is trying to access the next element to the last one which doesn't exists. If so, in your loop `$i < $c - 1` try this

Comment: can you print your array before using it in loop, i doubt that your array keys is not quoted as string.

Comment: It appears that `$menus` is a string array instead of a multi dimensional array.

Comment: $menus[$i]  is a string, not an array, and as such, has only numeric offsets.

Answer (score 0):

What PHP is saying is that at some iteration in

`if ($menuRights[$j]["rr_modulecode"] == $menus[$i]["mod_modulecode"]) {`

`$menus[$i]` is a string, not an array, and you're trying to access it like an array containing the key `mod_modulecode`.

To help track down this bug, I'd suggest:

```
if(is_string($menus[$i]) {
    var_dump('string bug','i',$i,'j',$j,'$menus[$i]',$menus[$i]);
}
if ($menuRights[$j]["rr_modulecode"] == $menus[$i]["mod_modulecode"]) {
```

Or even better yet, if you have `xdebug` installed, which will show local variables when an uncaught exception is thrown: `throw new Exception('string bug');`